# Is it always true? $\left|A-B\right| \le \left|A\right| + \left|B\right|$

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

Is it always right to claim that:
$$\left|A - B\right| \le \left|A\right| + \left|B\right|$$

where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: If you prove it for $A>B$ & then $A<B$, you can reach a conclusion.

Comment: Or if you prove it just for $ A \geq B $ as there is no loss of generality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.
$$|A-B|=|A+(-B)|\le|A|+|-B|=|A|+|B|.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Consider the cases where both $A$ and $B$ are either negative or positive (you should get an inequality)

Consider then the cases where one of them is negative and the other positive (you should get an equality)

(The cases where one or both are zero are trivial)

Comment: You don't get equality when $A = 2, B = 1$ (clearly both positive!)

Comment: @amWhy Sorry, my bad. The equality is when they have different sign and the inequality is when they have the same one. I'll edit that.

Comment: Exactly, Darth! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) in one-dimension.